# Selenium Grid + Jenkins + Python Not matching to node?

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently trying to run some parallel tests using Selenium Grid with Jenkins and Python.

Jenkins and the Selenium Plugin are working properly. Selenium Grid Hub is up and Nodes are sucessfully registered.

EDIT: I am using **Jenkins** with **Selenium Plugin** that means, I do not execute the hub and the nodes myself; jenkins does it for me with the ports and drivers I specified. Anyways I extracted this from the console

```
[Jenkins] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre\bin\java" -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar" hudson.remoting.Launcher -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\selenium\WEB-INF\lib\selenium-server-standalone-3.1.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\selenium\WEB-INF\lib\htmlunit-driver-standalone-2.20.jar" -connectTo localhost:49204
... More Selenium Grid Stuff...
INFORMATION: Will listen on 4444
Jul 13, 2017 7:42:40 AM org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry add
INFORMATION: Registered a node http://localhost:4445
```

I have a Hub running on Port 4444, and a Node running on Port 4445. Both are running in the same machine and the ports are unlocked.

Jenkins says the following in the Selenium Grid tab:

```
Configuration
Host: localhost
Port: 4444
Status: Online
...
Selenium 2 clients should connect as follow:
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

My problem is in my python code:

When I try to get a **remote webdriver using the hub URL and Port**:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

I get the following **error**:

```
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"status":13,"value":{"class":"java.lang.NullPointerException","stackTrace":[{"className":"j...adPool$3","methodName":"run","lineNumber":555},{"className":"java.lang.Thread","methodName":"run","lineNumber":-1}]}}'}
```

**But, when I use the Node port like this:**

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4445/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Then everything **works properly**.

Maybe I am understanding something wrong... Isn't Selenium Grid supposed to match the remote webdriver with an available node that matches the conditions?

What could be the problem? I've been googling like crazy and I just can't find anything related

***Note: I am quite sure that the desired_capabilities are correctly configured.***

Thank you!

Comment: Can you consider updating your question with the commands you used for starting the `Hub` and the `Node`? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I'm not the only one having this issue. There is actually a lot of people talking about this and waiting for a fix. If you are having the same trouble please take a look at this:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808

Also, this [comment](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3808#issuecomment-299861099) has a neat workaround that will make everything work properly until there is a fix.